# Reddit Api GET request succeeds in Postman, but fails with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, reddit, bearer-token

I am attempting to get a user's Reddit front page. I have successfully received an Auth Token via the [Token Retrieval (code flow)](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2). I have managed to get the expected JSON response via [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), but cannot produce the same results with Retrofit. The request seems to be timing out as onFailure() is being triggered in the callback. I am using the scopes: identity, mysubreddits, and read.

*Additional note: I have got a 401 and 403 response with the code below when using insufficient scopes and using an expired Auth Token respectively.*

Relevant constants:

```
redditToken = (actual auth token String)
RedditConstants.REDDIT_BASE_URL_OAUTH2 = "https://oauth.reddit.com"
```

Relevant method Section:

```
if (redditToken != null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RedditConstants.REDDIT_BASE_URL_OAUTH2)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "bearer " + redditToken);
        headers.put("User-Agent", RedditConstants.REDDIT_USER_AGENT);

        Call<RedditFeed> call = api.getFeed(headers);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RedditFeed>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RedditFeed> call, Response<RedditFeed> response) {
                Log.d("FINDME", "response "+ response.toString());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("FINDME", "response was a success! we got the feed!");
                } else {
                    Log.d("FINDME", "responce was not successfull triggered");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RedditFeed> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("FINDME", "onFailure called from populateRedditFeed");
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login with Reddit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Retrofit Interface:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET(".")
    Call<RedditFeed> getFeed (
            @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers
    );
}
```

Log Results:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using 
platform default
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=105KB
After code cache collection, code=111KB, data=79KB
D/FINDME: onFailure called from populateRedditFeed
```

Postman Success:

[image]

Comment: Print the throwable in the onFailure, it will give an idea what the error is. Post it here so we can help

Comment: Without any modifications to the code. I am now getting a successful  response. Before I was at Starbucks and now i'm using my home WiFi, perhaps that has something to do with it. I'll test it again tomorrow at Starbucks to confirm.

Comment: Haha cool :) good to know.... I could see that the code was fine and since you pointed out the 401 and 403 codes, i knew you knew about the auth token... That's why i had asked about the throwable log, anyway keep the log, it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

After many starts and stops, seemingly randomly getting either a 200 or calling onFailure() I discovered the problem in one of my Retrofit model classes. The [JSON response from Reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/JSON) contains a field that can either be a long or boolean. I had it defined as a boolean in my java class which threw an llegalStateException when it was returned as a long.

```
type      name      description
special   edited    false if not edited, edit date in UTC epoch-seconds 
                    otherwise. NOTE: for some old edited comments on reddit.com, this will 
                    be set to true instead of edit date.
```

*I'm unsure how to deal with this duality of types in java so for now I've commented out the field and the code works as expected.